# Best way to update UIView whenever new data is available

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgpoint

I have a `UIView` that I want to update whenever new data becomes available. Here's some context: I have a data structure that is constantly being updated in real time whenever the user hits a "start" button. The data structure receives vector data over time, and new vector data is added every few seconds. The way that I am trying to plot the vector data onto the `UIView` is with CGPoints. And I want to be able to call a function, give this function a set of `CGPoint`s, and just draw the line on the `UIView` as new data is added to the data structure. What is the best way to do this?

Here's what I have so far, but none of the lines are drawing onto the UIVIew:

```
class VectorDraw: UIView {

  var origin: CGPoint = .zero
  var point2: CGPoint = .zero


  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

      //Declaring context and its properties (i.e its width and color)
      let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
      context?.setLineWidth(3.0)
      context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.purple.cgColor)

      //Context directions, what to do with the context a move - addLine = stroke
      context?.move(to: origin)
      context?.addLine(to: point2)

      //Actually draws line
      context?.strokePath()
      print("Line drawn from origin at x: ", origin.x, "\tat y: ", origin.y)
      print("To terminal point at x: ", point2.x, "\tat y: ", point2.y)
  }
}
```

My idea was to just change the CGPoints when the start button is hit and then call `vectorDraw.setNeedsLayout()`, but the UIView doesn't update. The only lines that appear are when I have `CGPoints` set to different coordinates when the app opens.

Comment: I tried to do what you said, but it still is not drawing. There are print statements in the override draw function, and those aren't even printing to the console. Which tells me that this function isn't being called at all.

Comment: @Daniel Lyon I copied what you told me to into my viewDidLoad and didn't see anything new happen. I'm not sure if any of this is going to help, but here is some more information about my app. It generates vectors from the sensor components of the iphone. Once new CGPoints are generated I change `vectorDraw.origin` and `vectorDraw.point2`. In the same function on the next line I did what you asked of me in the previous comment. I typed in `vectorDraw.setNeedsLayout()` then `vectorDraw.layoutIfNeeded()`. When that didn't work, I tried just `vectorDraw.setNeedsDisplay()`. Still nothing has worked

Comment: I have a timer function, but its not called upon in either the `viewDidAppear` or the `viewDidLoad.` I have an IBAction function that calls the `startTimer()` and the `stopTimer()` function.

Comment: I apologize, I did not read that correctly. I did move it the `ViewDidAppear`, but that still did not work.

Comment: That did not work as well. What could be the issue? And is there any other additional information that you need to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Something else is supplying the coords to `VectorDraw` and you want `VectorDraw` to redraw every time the coordinate supplier updates? You'll have to resupply the new coordinates to `VectorDraw` and then call the `setNeedsDisplay()` function on `VectorDraw` to re-render the view

Comment: I've tried this, but calling `setNeedsDisplay()` anywhere in my code doesn't redraw the view.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. The problem I was having was that I was not updating the actual view, but an instance of the class view I had for drawing the line.

Here's an example in code: I had a variable `var vectorDraw = VectorDraw()` and I was trying to update the view like this `vectorDraw.setNeedsDisplay()`. The issue with this is that this is not the actual view; its just a object variable of VectorDraw. The solution I found (which I got from looking at this example: https://github.com/fujianjin6471/DemosForBlog/tree/master/SetNeedsDisplay) is that you need to connect the actual view from the main storyboard to the ViewController, which I somehow completely missed. If you control-drag from your view to your ViewController you get a variable like `@IBOutlet var vectorDrawView: VectorDraw!`. This is the variable you need to call `setNeedsDisplay()` with, and your view will update!

Comment: This is correct! And you learned an important lesson. However, this same question has been answered here many, many times already (I know because I've answered it many times myself). Making a new object instead of getting a reference to an existing object is a common beginner mistake. Moreover, you failed to _show_ the key code in your original question, so no one could possibly know what you were doing. So this question and answer doesn't really add anything new to the _site_.